# How to create a global view in Phoenix Framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I want to create a module with functions that can be accessed in every template and in which I can use all the functions of the view (creating tags, using router paths and etc), what is the best way to achieve that?

Simply put, how do I create a global view?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define a module (I'd put it in the helpers directory) that has your functions in it:

```
defmodule MyApp.SomeHelper do

  def some_function do
    #...
  end

end
```

You can then include it in `MyApp.Web` under the `view` function:

```
  def view do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"

      # Import convenience functions from controllers
      import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]

      # Import URL helpers from the router
      import MyApp.Router.Helpers

      # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
      use Phoenix.HTML

      # Import custom helpers
      import MyApp.SomeHelper
    end
  end
```

The `some_function` function will now be available in all templates.

Comment: I would have to also import `MyApp.Router.Helpers` and use `Phoenix.HTML` in this `MyApp.SomeHelper` to be able to use all view functions, wouldn't I?

Comment: It really depends on what your functions look like. If they use functions from `MyApp.Router.Helpers` and `Phoenix.HTML` then you will. Or you can use the long name. E.g. `MyApp.Router.Helpers.user_path(conn, :index)`